# Join and Update DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have two Table1 and Table2 whose columns with the values are given below:
These are the two tables:
I want to update "PaidAmount" in Table1. Join based on "InvoiceNo" column in both the tables.

**Table1:**

```
 InvoiceNo  Vendor   InvoiceValue  InvoiceDate      PaidAmount 
 ---------  ------   ------------- -----------      ---------- 
    1        AA        15000       01 Dec 2013         0      
    2        BB        20000       10 Dec 2013         0      
    3        CC        10000       18 Dec 2013         0
```

**Table2:**

```
 VoucherNo   Date       InvoiceNo  Amount
 -------   ----------- ----------  ------
   001     01 Nov 2013    1         5000
   002     10 Nov 2013    2         6000
   003     20 Nov 2013    3         7000
   001     02 Nov 2013    1         2000
```

My desired datatable should be like this:

**DesiredTable:**

```
 InvoiceNo  Vendor   InvoiceValue  InvoiceDate      PaidAmount 
 ---------  ------   ------------- -----------      ---------- 
     1        AA        15000       01 Dec 2013        7000      
     2        BB        20000       10 Dec 2013        6000
     3        CC        10000       18 Dec 2013        7000
```

How to achieve this result?
I have tried the below one.

```
Table1.AsEnumerable().Join(Table2.AsEnumerable(),
                      dt1_Row => dt1_Row.ItemArray[0],
                      dt2_Row => dt2_Row.ItemArray[2],
                      dt1_Row, dt2_Row) => new { dt1_Row, dt2_Row }
                      ).ToList()
                   .ForEach(o => o.dt1_Row.SetField(4, o.dt2_Row.ItemArray[3]));
```

But it gives the result as

```
InvoiceNo  Vendor   InvoiceValue  InvoiceDate      PaidAmount 
---------  ------   ------------- -----------      ---------- 
    1        AA        15000       01 Dec 2013        2000      
    2        BB        20000       10 Dec 2013        6000
    3        CC        10000       18 Dec 2013        7000
```

How to get my desired table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join give you a list of multiple row1, row2 couple.
So you are looping throught every couple, the first time for invoiceNo1, `row1.PaidAmount = 5000`, then your loop continue, and the second time, `row1.PaidAmount = 2000`, so your result.

You want to sum the Amount values of row2, so after joining, you have to group the datas by InvoiceValue, then perform a sum:

```
foreach(var grp in Table1.AsEnumerable()
      .Join(Table2.AsEnumerable(),
            dt1_Row => dt1_Row.ItemArray[0],
            dt2_Row => dt2_Row.ItemArray[2],
            dt1_Row, dt2_Row) => new { dt1_Row, dt2_Row }
       )
      .GroupBy(o => o.dt1_Row.ItemArray[0]))
{
    var row1 = grp.First().dt1_Row;
    var sum = grp.Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.dt2_Row.ItemArray[3]));
    row1.SetField(4, sum)
}
```

For more readibility, try to avoid using ForEach of List, it doesn't really improve your code.

Comment: It gives Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'decimal'.

Comment: I have updated the code with a conversion from object to int. What is the type of the field Amount?

Comment: decimal is the datatype for both amount and paidamount.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're iterating through your results and overwriting as opposed to adding to the pre-existing result from other rows. You would likely want to do something like this:

```
Table1.AsEnumerable().Join(Table2.AsEnumerable(),
                      dt1_Row => dt1_Row.ItemArray[0],
                      dt2_Row => dt2_Row.ItemArray[2],
                      dt1_Row, dt2_Row) => new { dt1_Row, dt2_Row }
                      ).ToList()
                   .ForEach(o => o.dt1_Row.SetField(4, o.dt1_Row.ItemArray[4] +  o.dt2_Row.ItemArray[3]));
```

Comment: It gives the following error: "Error 1 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'"

Comment: You would need to get the value of the object in the ItemArray. I don't know what the underlying type is of the items in your ItemArray. You likely need to cast it to an appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. You could use `GroupBy` to create invoice-groups and `ToDictionary` to create an efficient `InvoiceNo` to `PaidAmount` lookup. Then you just need a loop to update the rows:

```
var invoiceGroups = from r1 in Table1.AsEnumerable()
                    join r2 in Table2.AsEnumerable()
                    on r1.Field<int>("InvoiceNo") equals r2.Field<int>("InvoiceNo")
                    group r2 by r2.Field<int>("InvoiceNo") into InvoiceGroup
                    select InvoiceGroup;
Dictionary<int, int> invoiceSumLookup = invoiceGroups
    .ToDictionary(ig => ig.Key, ig => ig.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount")));
foreach(DataRow row in Table1.Rows)
    row.SetField("PaidAmount", invoiceSumLookup[row.Field<int>("InvoiceNo")]);
```

Note that this does not delete duplicate `InvoiceNo` rows from `Table1` if that's possible and not desired. It just groups the second table by that column and sums all `Amount`s.

It modifies the original table and does not need to create a new one.